# can't connect to oracle from win 2008 R2

Tags: visual-studio, oracle, odbc, oracleclient

i can't connect to oracle from windows 2008 R2  (connect from visual studio)

i have installed oracle client x64 , but still can't connect

> “Oracle client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation”

also i tried to connect trough ODBC but i couldn't

any ideas please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a pretty problem.  You will likely need to recompile your code with the Oracle data provider instead.

"Microsoft OLEDB Provider for Oracle and Microsoft ODBC driver for Oracle
If you are using Oracle data sources, you should migrate to the Oracle-supplied provider and driver. Microsoft OLEDB Provider for Oracle (msdaora.dll) and Microsoft ODBC driver for Oracle (msorcl32.dll) are built by using Oracle Call Interface (OCI) version 7. Oracle no longer supports applications that use OCI version 7 calls, and these technologies are deprecated. " --Microsoft

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/96048ef5-ef9e-4b1c-b8a3-5d7b91d55adb
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/267677/x64-version-of-msdaora-driver-please

Oracle ODAC
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Your question raises a few questions. What is the error message you get? Does your environment variables contain ORACLE_HOME?
For Oracle tools it is important to have some environment variables defined. Most important are ORACLE_HOME, should point to the directory where your Oracle client software is installed (you should have something like ORACLE_HOME\bin ORACLE_HOME\lib etc. Next, you should have the ORACLE_HOME\bin included in your PATH. I don't know about visual studio but this is how it normally should work. The wordsize of the client installation can be different than that of the rdbms installation but has to fit your application.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Upvote for the check whether you need the 32-bit and/or the 64-bit clients.